# jquery mobile checkbox and ASP .NET

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, .net, jquery-mobile

There is a problem with jquery mobile, form element- checkbox. So, i have a code in .cs file:

```
email = Request.Form["Email"];
password = Request.Form["password"];
rememberMe = Request.Form["remember_me"].AsBool();
```

As usually, this code have to fill variables with form data, but state of jquery mobile checkbox doesn't use 'checked' HTML markup. (http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/forms/checkboxes/index.html)

It's just change class in label like 'ui-checkbox-off/ui-checkbox-on'.

So, is it possible without big amount of code to check state of checkbox, created by jquery mobile?

Thx.

Comment: One decision, may be with hidden checkbox, but it's not really good =\

Comment: jQueryMobile docs say that the checked state is stored in the input[type=checkbox]. And if you take a look, you'll see that this is true. However, binding events to the 'change' event on such an input doesn't always work.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can do something like this?

```
<div data-role="fieldcontain" id="divCheckbox">
    <fieldset data-role="controlgroup">
       <legend>Agree to the terms:</legend>
       <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-1" id="checkbox-1" class="custom" />
       <label for="checkbox-1">I agree</label>
    </fieldset>
</div>
```

JS

```
$("#divCheckbox").click(function() {

    var checkbox = $(this).find("input[type='checkbox']");

    var label = $(this).find(".ui-checkbox-on");

    checkbox.prop("checked", label.length);
});
```

Not 100% sure but at least the DOM changes (see http://jsfiddle.net/rcSza/4/) Otherwise you can do something with a hidden field..